# Property of object not returning the expected value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am new to javascript and was trying to create a stopwatch object as described in a youtube video. Following is the code:

```
function Stopwatch(){
    let durationVal = 0;
    let startFlag = 0;

    this.start = function(){
            if (startFlag === 0){
                    durationVal = Date.now()
                    startFlag = 1;        
            }
            else{
                    throw new Error('Stopwatch is already running')
            }
    }

    this.stop = function(){
            if(startFlag === 1){
                    durationVal = Date.now() - durationVal
                    startFlag = 0;
            }
            else{
                    throw new Error('Stopwatch is not running')
            }
    }

    this.duration = durationVal;

    this.reset = function(){
            durationVal = 0;
    }
```

}

When I try to create an object and access its duration property

```
let sw = new Stopwatch()
sw.start()
sw.stop()
console.log(sw.duration)
```

It returns a zero. However, when I change my javascript to use a method to get the duration value:

```
 this.duration = function(){
            return durationVal;
 }
```

it gives the correct value.
Can you explain why?

Comment: `duration` gets its value once when it is a field; when the object is created (and `durationVal` is 0). You could use a property getter instead: `get duration() { return durationVal; }`

Comment: Either use `this.duration` or `durationVal` consistently.

Comment: If you want to be able to access it as a property, just use `this.duration` everywhere, get rid of `durationVal`.

Comment: Because the statement code `this.duration = durationVal;` only runs once when `new Stopwatch()` executes, whereas the function`function(){ return durationVal; }` runs every time you call it.

Comment: Thank you all :), I understood it now. this.duration is not getting updated as I make changes to durationVal.